# Building a Generic "Layout and Sizing" Configurable Dashboard Interafce

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to build a configurable dashboard interface and basically want to allow users to have an edit mode where they can resize the grid (including adding or removing columns and rows), drap&drop graph widget (built separately in an independent lib) on it but to resize the widget on the grid as they please. Before building this myself from scratch,

1> is there something already available that that I could reuse or extent?

2> If not and this has to be built, is jquery sortable the right thing to focus on building this?

Our app is based on bootstrap and backbone.

Comment: I think it's very specific thing you want. But with jQuery you can build a lot of things. If you use Backbone.js you can use Views to draw your dashboard or its parts.

Comment: I don't think this is very specific. This is a common theme in most dashboard interfaces.